# Add Same Text To Multiple Cells In One Column using Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery

I have an excel spreadsheet with two columns with example data

| Name | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| Dell v1 | 12 |
| HP v1 | 4 |

I've created a new sheet, and wanted to know which formula allows me to add the text value 'Dell v1' to 12 cells in a single column? I understand I can copy & paste, drag down etc....

| Name |
| --- |
| Dell v1 |
| Dell v1 |
| Dell v1 |
| Dell v1 |
| Dell v1 |
| Dell v1 |
| Dell v1 |
| Dell v1 |
| Dell v1 |
| Dell v1 |

Comment: Select all the cells, type, then use ctrl+enter

Comment: For more than one instance I need to know which formula I can use to accomplish this.

Comment: You can enter numbers, text or formulae with that method, for formulae make sure you get the referencing correct.

Comment: say you have a 1000 unique references with different values, Its a while to preform a manual fill. I'm asking for the formula alternative.

Comment: This would be a few small steps in PowerQuery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I have misunderstood the objective, with Office 365, you can do:

```
=LET( series, A2:A3,
      by, B2:B3,
       elements, SUM( by ),  eSeq, SEQUENCE( elements,,0 ),
       bySeq, SEQUENCE( ROWS( by ) ),
       byPos, MMULT( --(bySeq >= TRANSPOSE( bySeq )), by ),
       INDEX( series, IFERROR(MATCH( eSeq, byPos, 1 )+1,1), 0 ) )
```

where the Name is in **series** and the Quantities are in **by**.

[image]

### LAMBDA Helper

I just realized it could be shorter with a LAMBDA helper:

```
=LET( series, A2:A3,
      by, B2:B3,
       eSeq, SEQUENCE( SUM( by ),,0 ),
       byPos, SCAN(0,by,LAMBDA(a,b,a+b)),
       INDEX( series, IFERROR(MATCH( eSeq, byPos, 1 )+1,1), 0 ) )
```

Comment: I credited you allready, but on my way home I was thinking maybe you can make it even shorter where `XLOOKUP()` will replace the `INDEX()`, `MATCH()` and `IFERROR()` combination: `=LET(series,A2:A3,by,B2:B3,XLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(SUM(by)),SCAN(0,by,LAMBDA(a,b,a+b)),series,,1))`

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment, this seems to be a nice task for PowerQuery. Load your data from the table, and assuming the the name of the table to be 'table1', you can change the M-code in the advanced editor to the following:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Typed = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Name", type text}, {"Quantity", Int64.Type}}),
    Repeated = Table.TransformColumns(Typed, {"Quantity", each List.Numbers(_,_,0), type list}),
    Expanded = Table.ExpandListColumn(Repeated, "Quantity"),
    Finished = Table.RemoveColumns(Expanded,{"Quantity"})
in
    Finished
```

[image]

Then close PowerQuery and it will load the data back into Excel.

Comment: Sir, absolutely very simple with `Power Query` I have not shared, since you have added, by adding a custom column with list `{1..[Quantity]}` on expanding the same, it does the trick!

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya, yes, that would indeed be another nice alternative.

Comment: Sir, this what i used, `let
 Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table11"]}[Content],
 Duplicated = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each {1..[Quantity]}),"Custom"),
 #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Duplicated,{"Name"})
in
 #"Removed Other Columns"`

Answer (score 1):

Make it relatively easy by using helper column,

• In **A3** put the number 1

• In **A4** put formula `=A3+C3` and copy down

• In **E3** put formula

```
=VLOOKUP(ROW(A1),$A$3:$B$5,2,TRUE)
```

and drag down as far as it needs to go.

[image: Solution]